# What are the implications of API key to a third party?

Tags: api, telegram

I have, foolishly, provided my account phone-number +1xxxx , `api_id` and `api_hash` from my.telegram.org/apps to a third party. What could the security implications for that that account now be?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't provide your SMS code to third party, `api_id` and `api_hash` alone won't provide access to your account. Your data is still secure.

It's safe to publish `app_id` and `app_hash` in third party apps. You can find plenty of these in official and third party apps. In the worse case, other people may abuse your `app_id` casuing your `app_id` being banned.